# 1989 Mazda 626 - Shifter is loose, what's wrong?

Tags: transmission

I have an 89 Mazda 626 LX.  The shifter is really lose even when it's in gear.  It shifts fine, no slipping or anything, but when it's in gear I can move it back and forth as if it was in neutral.

How hard is it to fix, and does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: shifter? is this automatic or manual?

Comment: sorry, yes this is manual

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the shift linkage is not loose, this is probably caused by a worn shift bushing. A professional mechanic should be able to quickly check this. Replacing the bushing is generally inexpensive, although I do not know Mazdas.

Comment: Is this something that can easily be replaced? (anyone know?)

Comment: I think it's generally straightforward, but it has to be done from underneath the car.

Comment: This sounds like the '94 300ZX I bought back in 2005...  I had the dealer replace the shifter bushings, and after that it felt like a new car.  I don't recall exactly how much the bushings were, because I had a bunch of other things done at the same time.